# How to set selected file of asp:FileUpload from javascript without opening the file browse window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm developing a code where a file will be browsed and will be saved to the server.

But I want to retain the selected file even after file upload or page refresh. Is there any way to do this using javascript/jquery or plane asp.net?

```
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fileUploadControl" />
```

Comment: I don't think you can. A user always has to select a file. If you want the file available after a PostBack you need to store it temporarily somewhere and process it after the final PostBack.

Comment: you can do it if you are uploading file using ajax.

Comment: if page is refrshing it will not retain in fileupload so you need to use javascript

Comment: So ajax is the only solution??